# Calculate coordinates of a point after zooming in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, image-processing

I have a requirement to make some annotations on an image. This image is scalable (can be zoomed in and out). Now the challenge is that the annotations should also move with the scaling. How can I achieve this? I understand that 'direction' of zooming depends on the point considered as 'centre' when zooming, so assuming that this 'centre' is the absolute centre of the iamge container (width/2, height/2), how do I get the coordinates of the same point on image after zooming?

As an example, consider the following two images:

Image-1 (Normal scale):
[image]

Image-2 (Zoomed-in):
[image]

If I know the coordinates of the red point in Image-1 (which is at normal scale), how do I get the coordinates (x,y) of the same red point in Image-2? Note that the image container's width and height will remain same throughout the zooming process.

Comment: Get the x/y distance of your point from the center, multiple those with your scaling factor, and apply the resulting values from the center again …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function should return your new X and Y measured from the left top of the image. 
Bear in mind, that the new coordinates can be outside of the width/height of your image, as the point you picked might be "zoomed off the edge"

```js
/**
 * width: integer, width of image in px
 * height: integer, height of image in px;
 * x: integer, horizontal distance from left
 * y: integer, vertical distance from top
 * scale: float, scale factor (1,5 = 150%)
 */
const scaleCoordinates = (width, height, x, y, scale) =>{
 const centerX = width/2;
  const centerY = height/2;
  const relX = x - centerX;
  const relY = y - centerY;
  const scaledX = relX * scale;
  const scaledY= relY * scale;
  return {x: scaledX + centerX, y: scaledY + centerY};
  

}

console.log(scaleCoordinates(100,100,25,50, 1.2));
```

Comment: I believe that all parameters of `scaleCoordinates` i.e. `width`, `height`, `x`, `y` will remain same throughout? Only the `scale` would change?

Comment: If the image size doesn't change, the first 2 stay the same. 
If the annotation point doesn't change, the second 2 don't change.

Comment: If I drag this image, is it possible to move the annotations with it?

Comment: If you alter the code a bit you can... In the question you specified that the zooming would be done from the center. What you propose now is that you zoom and drag. That basically is an "off-center zoom".

Don't know what your UI looks like. Might be easier to zoom using the center and than just move the annotations the same amount as you drag the image around.
You can

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the mathematical formula in `scaleCoordinates` function? I didn't understand why you added `centerX` to `scaledX` and `centerY` to `scaledY` in the last step?

Answer (score 1):

First, you'd want to determine the coordinates of the annotation with respect to the center of the image.

So for example on an image of 200 x 100, the point (120,60) with the origin in the left top corner would be (20,-10) when you take the center of the image as your origin.

If you scale the image 150%, your new coordinates would be those coordinates multiplied by 1,5 (=150%).
In our example that would be 30, -15.

Than you can calculate that back to absolute values, with the original point of origin

Comment: "the point (120,60) with the origin in the left top corner would be (20,-10) when you take the center of the image as your origin." - I didn't quite get this statement.

Comment: The coordinate systems don't really match. I know. In web we normally use left top as 0,0, with down and right  as positive directions. Image should make it more clear. 
https://m.imgur.com/gallery/K3szYCr

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/4hmbb8K_d.jpg?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium

Comment: Excellent answer - focusing on the approach rather than the code. That being said, you should have edited the answer to match the coordinate systems instead of linking to an image that might be lost in the future. All you needed to do was to change the initial origin to the left bottom corner, or set the point to (120,40) to match the -10 and -15 values, or let the point as it is and set the values to 10 and 15.

Comment: @YinCognyto I'm not sure if the difference or the initial origin (top left v.s. bottom left) was the issue for darKnight, or if it was changing the origin to the center to keep things aligned when zooming. I assumed the latter.

Comment: @JasperZelf It doesn't really matter what was the issue for darKnight, as he already got to the desired result by now. I was talking more about the value of the answer for present (like me) and future users reading it. The fact that the origins are not consistent throughout the answer takes a bit from its quality and clarity, and has the potential of confusing those reading it - and this was the reason I suggested picking one of the 3 possible edits to make it better. That being said, my previous comment is already posted, so maybe that's enough to achieve the same outcome...